# SOAP Authorization

Tags: php, authentication, soap, authorization

The web service I'm trying to consume has such a WSDL file: http://dgpysws.teias.gov.tr/dgpys/services/EVDServis?wsdl

I'm trying to consume "setIkiliAnlasma" service, however accessing that service requires authentication. I have my credentials and when I make a SOAP call to login service it authenticates my credentials.

And as expected, when I call "setIkiliAnlasma" service I get an Authorization error. What is the method to combine authorization supplied by login call with the main service I need to consume?

By the way the programming language I'm usign is **PHP** and the native **SoapClient** functions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php

Comment: How are you authenticating  ? can you post an example ?

Comment: I'm supposed to use the login method provided by the WSDL file, you can see it in the wsdl or see http://goo.gl/G2PJk

Comment: see my answer below - added some code as an example of how to use authentication with a webservice - I can see the login method and also the output from that method is a loginResponse - use the code in my answer and update it to match your wsdl ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of using the SOAPClient in PHP with authentication - you just need to adapt it to the WSDL you are using ->

```
// Setting "trace" will allow us to view the request that we are making, after we have made it.
$objClient = new SoapClient("http://www.somewhere.com/wsdls/some.wsdl", array('trace' => true)); 

// These parameters satisfy this specific remote call.
$arrParameters_Login = array('username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password');

// Invoke the remote call "login()".
$objLogin =  $objClient->login($arrParameters_Login); 

// Grab session ID that this remote call will provide.
$strSessionID = $objLogin->loginReturn->sessionId;
```

You will then need to use the sessionid / session code that is sent to you in the login response - maybe in a header - its specific to each WSDL.

Comment: Yes Manseuk you are right. I'm using raw SOAP calls with ``SoapClient::__doRequest`` and login call responses an Apache Axis2 UUID. That session id is supposed to be referred in the latter calls.

Comment: How is it done after authorization? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66707432/php-client-for-soap-server-requests-after-authorization

Answer (score 1):

try to use this way to authenticate when calling the soap client url :

http://username:password@domain.com/

Comment: Web service authorization is done by the **login service** in the WSDL file not by HTTP Auth.